# replace \t\t characters with <br> character rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am making a parser of some website. 
As an output from parser I get string like:

```
"some text \t\t some another text \t\t another text"
```

I want to replace `\t\t` with `<br>`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Use gsub: `"some text \t\t some another text \t\t another text".gsub("\t\t", '<br />')`

Comment: i tried to write something like `.gsub('\t\t', '<br>')`but this doesn't work

Comment: Use double quotes for the pattern, single quotes wouldn't work.

Comment: @theTinMan don't get your point. read my comment under post. I provided what I tried to do there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gsub`:

```
"some text \t\t some another text \t\t another text".gsub("\t\t", "<br>")
=> "some text <br> some another text <br> another text"
```